# In what sense are Pauli matrices "intertwiners"?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, clifford-algebras, spin-geometry

I'm trying to understand the following quote from the [Wikipedia article on the Pauli matrices](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Pauli_matrices#Pauli_vector).

> More formally, this defines a map from $\mathbb {R} ^{3}$ to the vector space of traceless Hermitian $2\times 2$ matrices. This map encodes structures of $\mathbb {R} ^{3}$ as a normed vector space and as a Lie algebra (with the cross-product as its Lie bracket) via functions of matrices, making the map an isomorphism of Lie algebras. This makes the Pauli matrices intertwiners from the point of view of representation theory.

I understand everything except for the last sentence. I know what an intertwining map is, but what is an "intertwiner"? More importantly, the definition of an intertwining map $\phi:V\to W$ requires that we have linear representations (of the Lie algebra $\frak{so}(3)$, in this case) on $V$ and $W$. I understand that $\mathbb R^3$ with the cross product is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{so}(3)$, but this is not a typical linear representation, where the representatives of Lie algebra elements are linear maps and $\rho([X,Y])=\rho(X)\rho(Y)-\rho(Y)\rho(X)$. So what does the last sentence mean exactly?

Comment: Anybody can edit Wikipedia articles, no matter how little they understand the subject.

Comment: Yeah I think this is some dodgy use of language. I think you could argue a $SO(3)$-equivariant map from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $i\mathfrak{su}_2$ (which is the correct span of the Pauli matrices) is an intertwiner but not the matrices themselves. By this token any isomorphism of Lie algebras is an intertwiner though so this isn't an important point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that your objection is exactly right. That is, the Pauli matrices are literally a/the standard basis for the (complexified?!) Lie algebra $\mathfrak sl(2)$. Yes, $\mathbb R^3$ with cross product is another 3-dimensional Lie algebra, and (maybe complexified?) is isomorphic to $\mathfrak sl(2)$.

I'd call the map a "Lie algebra isomorphism".

As you say, there are not really any *representations* in sight, and an "intertwiner" would usually be a map from one repn (of a fixed thing) to another repn (of that same thing), that preserves/respects the action (of the fixed thing).

So, yes, I agree with your appraisal that the terminology "intertwiner" in that situation is not standard, at least in the mathematics that I know, or the physics-y stuff that I know, either. But, still, conceivably, there is another milieu in which this abuse of terminology is standard, too.

Answer (score 0):

A Lie group operates on its Lie algebra via the adjoint representation which is the conjugation for matrix Lie algebras. This means in case of unitary matrices
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Ad}\, : \,\operatorname{SU}(2,\mathbb{C})&\longrightarrow \operatorname{SO}(\mathfrak{su}_\mathbb{R}(2,\mathbb{C)},\mathbb{R})\cong \operatorname{SO}(3,\mathbb{R})\\
\operatorname{Ad}\, : \,u&\longmapsto (X\longmapsto u^{-1}Xu)
\end{align*}
The Pauli matrices, however,
\begin{equation} \sigma_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\, , \, \sigma_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -i \\ i & 0 \end{bmatrix}\, , \, \sigma_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix} \end{equation}
are hermitian, not skew-hermitian as required!

We either have to make them skew-hermitian by substituting them with $\{i\cdot \sigma_1,i\cdot \sigma_2,i\cdot \sigma_3\}$ as a basis of
$$
\mathfrak{su}(2,\mathbb{C})=\{X \in \mathbb{M}(2,\mathbb{C})\,|\,\operatorname{trace}X=0\wedge X+\overline{X}^T=0\}
$$
or drop the requirement that the representation space is a Lie algebra:
$$
\sigma_k + \overline{\sigma_k}^T=2\sigma_k\quad , \quad(i\sigma_k)+\overline{(i\sigma_k)}^T=0
$$

Comment: I don't see how this answers my question.

Comment: That is the only reason I can think of that gives the word "intertwine" at least a bit of a sense. The Pauli matrices are for physics, mathematicians would use their $i$-th multiple for a consistent representation theory.

Answer (score 0):

Pauli matrices are indeed an intertwining map.

A quick look is by checking the indices: $\sigma^{i}_{ab}$, where $i$ is the $su(2)$ vector index and $a,b$ are $su(2)$ spin indices. Similarly, the $\Gamma$ matrices are also an intertwining map, $\sigma^{\mu}_{\dot{a}b}$, where $\dot{a}b$ is the standard dotted-undotted notation, and the indices run over finite-dim representations of $sl(2,C)$.

For a more precise answer we need to specify the corresponding representation spaces. The claim is that Pauli matrices are components of the intertwining map from $1/2\otimes 1/2$ to $1$. I'll use Mathematica to show calculations and only work out the case of Pauli matrices.

Recall the matrix coefficients in the tensor product decomposition of $su(2)$,
\begin{equation}
1/2\otimes 1/2=1\oplus 0
\end{equation}
is called the Clebsch–Gordan coefficients. They are

```
f[c_]:=Table[
    ClebschGordan[{1/2,a},{1/2,b},{1,c}],
    {a,1/2,-1/2,-1},
    {b,1/2,-1/2,-1}
];
f/@{-1,0,1}//Map[MatrixForm]
```

[image]

At first glance, it seems that the three CG matrices don't match the Pauli matrices. There are two points left:

1. the basis of spin-1 representation is the so-called spherical basis of vector. $v_{x,y,z}\to v_{\pm,0}$;
2. the row and column spaces of the Pauli matrices are not canonically the same one. One is $1/2$ and the other is the dual of $1/2$. The dual is equivalent to itself by an intertwining map $\epsilon$,
   \begin{equation}
   \epsilon \sigma=-\sigma^{*}\epsilon
   \end{equation}
   where the Pauli matrices themselves are representation matrices of $1/2$.

Exercise: show that $\epsilon=\{\{0,1\},\{-1,0\}\}$.

Then we need to change the basis of the Clebsch–Gordan coefficients by multiplying the $\epsilon$ operator,

```
ep={{0,1},{-1,0}}
f/@{-1,0,1}//Map[Dot[ep,#]&]//Map[MatrixForm]
```

[image]
and get the Pauli matrices in the spherical basis.